# convert a JavaScript string to a Javascript object. Using JSON class does not work

Tags: javascript, json

From the backend I get a **string**(nothing I could handle with **JSON.parse** or **JSON.stringify**):

```
"{
  Search_Ids: [
    { "searchId": "428784921" },
    { "searchId": "428784922" },
    { "searchId": "428784923" },
    { "searchId": "428784924" },
    { "searchId": "428784925" }
  ],
  Checksum: 5
}"
```

I want to convert a **JavaScript string** to a **Javascript object**.
Using JSON class does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" is not an adequate problem description. What is the actual behaviour you observe?

Comment: It's not a valid string literal, they can't contain line breaks like that. Remove them. And you can't have unquoted double quotes inside double quotes, etc.

Comment: Is the problem about keys like `Search_Ids` not quoted in your input? Do you control the backend, is it possible to fix it?

Comment: It is also not valid JSON: property names need to be quoted.

Comment: @RobG, it's more `Search_Ids` and `Checksum` are not quoted correctly.

Comment: @NinaScholz—yeah, should have stopped at invalid… ;-)

Comment: NB: In JavaScript `JSON` is not a class, [but an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: assigning the string to a variable without the quotation marks works like this : `var x={
  Search_Ids: [
    { "searchId": "428784921" },
    { "searchId": "428784922" },
    { "searchId": "428784923" },
    { "searchId": "428784924" },
    { "searchId": "428784925" }
  ],
  Checksum: 5
};` with quation marks at the beginning does not work

Comment: @JaneKins—that is an object literal, it's the notation that JSON is based on but it does not make an object literal "JSON". ;-)

Comment: There's still a valid question here that hasn't been answered: given a string representing a JavaScript object literal (not JSON), how to safely parse it without eval? @trincot

Comment: @Kos: Answer to that is: don't. If looking for a *safe* solution, don't accept a back-end sending you JavaScript that you would need to parse. The back-end should use the accepted standard: JSON.